# Will upgrading a chaincode remove the previous data stored in the ledgers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am learning Hyperledger Fabric. I tried updating the chaincode of the FabCar Network. After I restart the Fabric, I see that all previous data stored in the ledger is lost. 
Will updating chaincode cause previous data to be lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fabric separates state from the version/instance of chain code.  This makes it possible to update your chaincode logic without actually losing your state.

In order to do this, you need to perform a chaincode upgrade transaction (prior to this you need to install the upgraded chaincode on each peer).

My guess is that your issue occurred because you actually brought the network up and down, modified the chaincode and then brought it back up again.  In the samples, bring the network down is generally a destructive action ... `docker-compose down` actually destroys your container instances which wipes out the state data unless you are using external volumes (the sample networks do not do this).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I did. In a production system, if we have to do this, I guess you have to set up external volumes? Can you please explain a bit more about this? If external volumes are not set, will the ledger data be lost if the entire network somehow crashes ?

Comment: @vvictor yes, if you are not using external docker volumes  or kubernetes pvc’c then data will be lost it means it will not persistence data when container destroyed

Comment: By default, containers store data within their own container file system.  If the container is destroyed, all data in the container is destroyed as well.  If you stop/start a container and/or the container crashes, then you can restart the container and the data will exist (not recommended to rely on this at all though.

Answer (score 2):

Happy learning !!

Coming to your question, Upgrading chaincode is safe. You are just updating the logic, it will not harm to your existing data, you might have disturbed the ledger thats why it misbehaved.

You must send an upgrade proposal in order to complete the upgrade process.

A chaincode may be upgraded any time by changing its version, which is part of the SignedCDS. Other parts, such as owners and instantiation policy are optional. However, the chaincode name must be the same; otherwise it would be considered as a totally different chaincode.

Prior to upgrade, the new version of the chaincode must be installed on the required endorsers. Upgrade is a transaction similar to the instantiate transaction, which binds the new version of the chaincode to the channel.